# Books for Operation Systems, Protocols

Tags: operating-system, embedded

I am interested in learning in depth about operating systems - especially embedded OSs and the protocol stacks they support like Ethernet, Bluetooth, Serial, IRDA, etc....

Is there a comprehensive book or online resource that will guide me in this direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two books I would recommend to start with

- Title: Programming Embedded Systems: With C and GNU Development Tools, 2nd Edition
- Author: M. Barr
- Publisher: O'Reilly Media; 2 edition (October 1, 2006)
- Language: English
- ISBN-10: 0596009836
- ISBN-13: 978-0596009830

and

- Title: MicroC OS II: The Real Time Kernel (With CD-ROM)
- Author: J.J. Labrosse
- Publisher: Newnes; 2 edition (June 15, 2002)
- Language: English
- ISBN-10: 1578201039
- ISBN-13: 978-1578201037

which explain the concepts of task, queues, semaphores and mutexes in great detail.

There is also *"uC/OS-III, The Real-Time Kernel, or a High Performance, Scalable, ROMable, Preemptive, Multitasking Kernel for Microprocessors, Microcontrollers & DSPs"* which is newer, but I haven't read it, so I can not recomment it.

Answer (score 1):

Reading and understanding the code of open source projects also helps. If possible, download the source code, build and run in your own board, and then try to change stuff around. Add a new process to the system, a cool little feature that interests you and you will learn a lot from it. Not to mention the satisfaction and fun you get from seeing your project run.

These are some open source embedded OSs you could try.

http://www.sics.se/contiki/

The Contiki OS is small and designed for things with small memory requirements.

Another popular Embedded OS is Tiny OS. ( tiny OS dot net)

I hope this helps, I know you asked about books, but you will get a lot from trying it out on your own.

Answer (score 1):

The basics are covered best IMHO in the book by Andrew S. Tanenbaum, "Modern Operating Systems" (http://www.amzn.com/0136006639). The latest edition includes the basics in the first half, and more modern concepts (multimedia, multiple processors, networking and security) and a 'comparison' between Unix/Linux and Win2K.

To experiment yourself, there's the alternative of Minix (still kept alive!), a small Unix derivative originated by Tanenbaum as well, as a teaching vehicle for his students in the 80s: http://www.minix3.org/.

If the interfaces you listed are your main objective, I cannot recommend a single book. I'd myself take a whole stack of books, since one book cannot cover both the breadth and the depth I would require. YMMV.

BR,

Johan